# VScode docker - Can't attach to bash running the Docker container

Tags: bash, docker, visual-studio-code

The Docker extension for VS-code attaches /bin/sh to your containers by default. The settings file confirms this:

```
"docker.attachShellCommand.linuxContainer": "/bin/sh"
```

I have changed this in the settings editor of VS-code to attach to bash instead:

```
"docker.attachShellCommand.linuxContainer": "/bin/bash"
```

I expected to get `/bin/bash` as CLI when attaching to the container. Instead, it still attached me to `/bin/sh`.

Comment: Contains your container /bin/bash?

Comment: Can you give some more information?
- what container are you using? 
- can you attach the output of a docker inspect on that container?

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime, I'm a day further and the behaviour of my shell has changed to the behaviour of /bin/bash. This is confusing.

After even more experimenting, I found out that I have a problem with the Chrome cache. I installed a clear-cache button in Chrome, which allowed me to clear the cache whenever I suspected this problem. Now I am in control. I did nothing wrong with the settings.

Question answered. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues trying to use:

```
"docker.attachShellCommand.linuxContainer": "/bin/bash"
```

Getting and error:

```
    "The terminal process failed to launch: Path to shell executable "/bin/bash" does not exist.
```

Ended up reverting back to:

```
"docker.attachShellCommand.linuxContainer": "/bin/sh"
```